# Keycloak, Wildfly and JSF - 'Forbidden'

Tags: jsf, wildfly, keycloak

Good day friends

First of all, I read the documentation, Googled and tried various methods.

I am trying to secure a JSF 2.2 webapp running as a WAR deployed app on Wildfly_11.0.0.0_Final.

Keycloak is setup with the correct realm information and have ROLES and USERS defined.

Logging in to the Keycloak account (for admin and users) works 100%

Without 'activating' Keycloak the app works fine (it loads and all navigation works, and the ui is mostly PrimeFaces and OmniFaces).

When 'activating' Keycloak (and running it on a port offset to ensure the ports do not clash with WildFly) all I get is a 'Forbidden' page after authenticating with Keycloak.

All I want to do is to have access to the security token inside the app to be able to render UI fragments and access bean methods based on the ROLES assigned to a user.

Right, here is my current attempt's setup and related info (if one of you gurus see something not related to this specific question, that can be improved, all feedback will be most appreciated).

My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <!-- Model Version -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- mvn version prerequisite -->
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <!-- Application package information -->
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Properties -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <!-- mvn repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>public-jboss</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net-maven2-SNAPSHOT-repository</id>
            <name>Java.net SNAPSHOT-Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net-maven2-repository</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-snapshot</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Server specific dependencies for WildFly 11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Target dependency for Java EE 7 server. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime dependencies.  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-spi</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2.redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final-redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-feature-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnisettings</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omniutils</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnipersistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>optimusfaces</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test dependencies. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <!-- Build settings -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My keycloak.json file located in: /WEB-INF/keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "MyRealm",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:62223/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "myapp",
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username"
}
```

The contents of my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.1"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <!-- Application information -->
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <description>MyApp description.</description>


    <!-- App Security -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>myapp</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>


    <!-- context params -->
    <!-- Save State On Client -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- enable development mode -->
    <context-param>
        <description>
            Development version of MyApp
        </description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.weld.development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- convert to local timezone -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- PrimeFaces setup -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- log4j -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
        <param-value>myapp</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Welcome File -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

The xml portion copied from the 'Installation' tab in Keycloak, then pasted into standalone.xml file for Wildfly looks like this:

```
subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
          <secure-deployment name="myapp.war">
            <realm>MyRealm</realm>
            <auth-server-url>http://localhost:62223/auth</auth-server-url>
            <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
            <resource>myapp</resource>
            <credential name="secret">ce0984f0-c6ef-4808-bfd4-342480437051</credential>
            <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
          </secure-deployment>
        </subsystem>
```

I have an index.xhtml file located in /webapp/index.xhtml (ie not inside the WEB-INF folder).

What I want to happen, is for only after a successful authentication, should the users be redirected to the index.xhtml file. This file then accesses templates and CRUD files below the /WEB-INF/ folder.

I found example code at https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-javaee-demo that will allow me to read a user's roles and based on the roles partially render the UI and menus.

Please let me know if you require any other info related to the above.

Sincerest thanks

EDIT: Added screenshot of the Keycloak client settings tab

[image: screenshot of the Keycloak client settings tab]

Comment: Have you configured the Realm client for your Java application properly? What are your web origins in client configuration?

Comment: @Dino Hi Dino, my Web Origins has one entry and is "http://localhost:8080"

Comment: @Dino I changed the values to * and + and also included a screenshot of this tab, if that will help.

Comment: It seems fine. What I can suggest you is first checking the roles of the user you are trying to log in with. Forbidden may be caused by this.

Comment: @Dino, thanks will do.

Comment: @Dino I checked the roles assigned to the users, and they seem fine. Still getting the 'Forbidden' screen though.

Comment: Would be also useful if you could post the log from keycloak server.

Comment: @Dino see the log file here: https://pastebin.com/ZQ5AshEc there is only one warning and that is for the H2 database: Unable to determine H2 database version. No other warnings or errors whatsoever.

Comment: I was thinking about the log right after you get 'Forbidden' screen. Not the actual log of starting the kc server

Comment: @Dino where would that log file be? I looked at the keycloak log files and the other wildfly server (on which the app is hosted) log files, and no WARN or ERROR in any of them. How can I find the log you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161620/discussion-between-dino-and-georgelappies).